# CSS "height: 100%;" not taking into consideration siblings with height, leading to unnecessary overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a div of height 100%. Inside that div, there are two children: an `<a>` and another `<div>`. The child `<div>` also has a height of 100%. I expected setting the child div's height to 100% would make it fill up the remaining height, not copy the height of the parent element and disregard fellow children leading to unintended overflow.

Example: https://codepen.io/gamepro5/pen/Jjpaqva (why is the child class in this example overflowing it's parent with a height of 100%?)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.child{
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
  /*would need to do a calc of 100% minus whatever the height of the <a> tag is, but that is annoying to do since the height of the other items can change. */
}
.child p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <a>Daddy Potato (king of all potatoes):</a>
      <div class="child"><p>Potatoe</p><p>Potatoe</p><p>Potato</p><p>Potate</p><p>Ube</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I simply want the child div to fill up the remaining available space with it's height without overflowing.

Comment: `height:100%;` indeed means "same as the entire inner height of the container", regardless of sibling elements - that's how legacy CSS flow works.

If you want a flexible layout that can be aware of the container and siblings and fill gaps in, you would have to use either a flex or a gird layout.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with flex: Set `display: flex` and `flex-flow: column;` on the parent element, and on the child set `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;

  height: 100%;
}
.child{
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}
.child p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <a>Daddy Potato (king of all potatoes):</a>
      <div class="child"><p>Potatoe</p><p>Potatoe</p><p>Potato</p><p>Potate</p><p>Ube</p></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the child div is also a flexbox, when it comes time for that box to start wrapping the elements inside it, it will ignore your fix and use cause the same scrolling issue. It refuses to start wrapping when there is no space left with respect to the sibling. Instead, it only starts wrapping when the window is under 100% the height of it's parent. Any way to fix that if the child div is also display: flex;?

Comment: Simply by adding another wrapper, so your child will have a flex-grow, and the child of the child will have a display: flex;

Comment: This doesn't work when the height of the sibling in question has to be precisely set

Comment: @JohnMiller there is nothing in the question that mentions that the height of the sibling must be precisely set. Running example from the question and running my example with the fix, you can see that everything works as expected for this question.

Comment: You're not wrong, but would it be a more helpful and clearer answer if a disclaimer were put at the top? It's super annoying to spend a chunk of time implementing a solution like this only to find out the hard way, especially when the answer in question doesn't seem to provide an answer to the title of the question, which is the only thing that actually matters (nobody reads the whole content of a long question, the title is enough 95% of the time)